# Postgres PGP_SYM_DECRYPT and PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT where search with Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, encryption, sequelize.js

I have a question about **PGP_SYM_DECRYPT and PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT with Sequelize**.
I have the Encrypted data in the Database, but when I want to search by key I cannot find it because the key is not encrypted back when sent from where clause.

```
return await database.Example.findOne({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.fn('PGP_SYM_DECRYPT', Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('value'), 'bytea'), process.env.AES_ENCRYPTION_KEY), 'value'],
      [Sequelize.fn('PGP_SYM_DECRYPT', Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('key'), 'bytea'), process.env.AES_ENCRYPTION_KEY), 'key'],
    ]
  },
  where: { key, user_id: id }
});
```

**PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT in where** clause doesn't work for me, any thoughts? Thank you

```
where: { key: Sequelize.fn('PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT', key, process.env.AES_ENCRYPTION_KEY), user_id: id }
```